# Check if a process is running and if not, restart it using Cron

Tags: bash, shell, unix, awk, cron

I have created restart.sh with followin code

```
#!/bin/bash
ps -aux | grep sidekiq > /dev/null
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
  echo "Process is running."
else
  echo "Process is not running."
fi
```

To check if sidekiq process is running or not. I will put this script in cron to run daily so if sidekiq is not running, it will start automatically.

My problem is, with

```
ps -aux | grep sidekiq
```

even when the process is not running, it shows

```
myname 27906  0.0  0.0  10432   668 pts/0    S+   22:48   0:00 grep --color=auto sidekiq
```

instead of nothing. This gets counted in grep hence even when the process is not running, it shows as "sidekiq" process is running. How to not count this result ? I believe I have to use awk but I am not sure how to use it here for better filtering.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To exclude the `grep` result from the `ps` output. Do

```
ps -aux | grep -v grep | grep sidekiq
```

(or) do a `regEx` search of the process name, i.e. `s` followed by rest of the process name.

```
ps -aux | grep [s]idekiq
```

To avoid such conflicts in the search use process `grep` [`pgrep`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/pgrep) directly with the process name

```
pgrep sidekiq
```

An efficient way to use `pgrep` would be something like below.

```
if pgrep sidekiq >/dev/null
then
     echo "Process is running."
else
     echo "Process is not running."
fi
```

Comment: Hmm. Nice touch :) I  guess the op has already figured out the root cause of the problem which is the line `ps -aux | grep sidekiq > /dev/null` in his script..In particular I liked the second solution which is clinical.

Comment: @inian - grep -v grep worked perfectly and now the script is running. pgrep sidekiq somehow is giving nothing when I run in terminal even though the process is running. May be it is because the way sidekiq works ?

Comment: There's no need to redirect things to `/dev/null`. Just use the `-q` option, for either `grep` or `pgrep`.

Comment: Not all versions of pgrep support `-q`